# How to deal with all the questions raised due to recent DoS attacks?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

The last 4~5 weeks the ethereum network was stress-tested by some malicious parties who exploited too low gas prices as potential DoS vector. In one case it caused the whole network's geth nodes to crash. Later the network was affected by basicly everything which could stress clients: high CPU processing, high memory consumption and insane I/O due to malicious transactions being processed.

The effect on this stack exchange subsite is that there are users asking over and over about the similar symptoms again. But it's far away from being a duplicate in many cases. The problems are so diverse ranging from all the different clients and operating systems affected to the range of different attacks which cause different symptoms.

I really could not wrap my head around a solution and in the end I keep either answering the questions with specific solutions for each user or adding comments teaching about the attacks and the recent hard fork.

But that's exhausting. Does anyone have a good idea on how to deal with all the issues due to recent DoS attacks?

Comment: We have the same problem over on Bitcoin.SE with questions about transactions not confirming. Sometimes the right answer is 'just wait,' but other times that won't help. If you figure this out, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this very well explained answer by Booky as master for all up and coming questions and close them as duplicate.

- [Why is my node synchronization stuck/extremely slow at block 2,306,843?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/9883/87)

And often these threads are good related references, too, which could be linked in comments as well:

- [Is it possible to make the Parity software sync faster?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/10465/87)
- [Parity 1.4.4: syncing stopped at some block (actually is very slow)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/10283/87)
- [What is Parity's “warp” sync, and why is it faster than Geth "fast"?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/9991/87)
- [Running Wallet 0.8.6 with Parity 1.3.8 [Low # peers, Low speed]](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/9402/87)
- [Blocks are not being downloaded](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/9002/87)
- [Is there a quicker way than geth --fast to download the Ethereum blockchain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/4293/87)
- [What is Geth's "fast" sync, and why is it faster?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1161/87)
- [Help with very slow mist sync](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/603/87)
- [How can I get a geth node to download the blockchain quickly?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/392/87)